# MVC3 performance issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc, dynamic-data

We have a website built on MVC3 and Telerik. After the latest release, we've got huge performance issues ( all the pages load about 40-50 seconds). As far as we can see in our dev environments, old and new release work absolutely fine. Whereas on prod, loading any page remotely works extremely slow. However, from prod box itself, using localhost or hostname, it works fine too.
What we have already checked:

1. database works absolutely fine
2. old/new releases on all the QA,DEV envs
3. application pool settings were compared with other websites, which are working fine
4. Application pool recycling counter - no unexpected recycles
5. Different browsers - also checked
6. Chrom dev tools show that all the time spends on getting data from the server (I believe rendering the page on the server). All the Ajax request work fast.

To be fair, I run out of thoughts what it might be, so can you please suggest what else worth checking in this case (network setting, IIS settings, perf counters and etc)?

Comment: if it is taking 40 seconds, that definitely isn't normal and isn't some inbuilt feature of MVC3 - so: it is *something* in your setup; I'm not sure how we can remotely diagnose that, unfortunately...

Comment: @MarcGravell totally agree, but i'm asking about what worth checking

Comment: Maybe you need to check your DNS if it has problem with resolving the names since your app is working fine when requesting it from localhost

Comment: Check the following things: 1. Is something depriving your app access to the database. In our case, we had a Tableau process that would hog all database connections and will not allow our app to get appropriate database cycles. 2. Write a very simple method like GetServerTime that simply fetches time from the database. See if this also takes time.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a proxy or other intermediary server in play? 
If performance is acceptable when you browse locally but poor remotely I would first check the path to the website when you visit it remotely via traceroute or something similar. If the hoops are as expected, I would check the boxes along the way to your website to make sure they are not doing something weird. If you guys use a CDN, I would check if it still configured correctly. Failing that I would look at perhaps adding some client side instrumentation so you can see whats actually taking long, something like [this](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/#preparing-for-a-proxy-client-timings) perhaps.

Answer (score -2):

If you have action filters enabled try disabling them and test. Might be some action filters are doing an extra work which delays the response.